# Movie and Year exist in one query but not both

Tags: sql, oracle10g, exists

I have two queries, the first one returns a movie and year which has movies which has more then two cast members and the second query displays the movies which have won more than two awards.

So I want to write a query which will give me the movie and year which occurs in one query but not both. How will I able to do this?

The syntax is in Oracle.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: No minus will not work.

Comment: Put MINus between selects

Comment: I did, but then it says no rows selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this MINUS

First set is rows that exists in table1 alone

Second set is rows that exists only on table2

```
 SELECT * FROM table1
 MINUS
 SELECT * FROM table2

 UNION

 SELECT * FROM table2
 MINUS
 SELECT * FROM table1
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write a query which will give me the movie and year which
>   occurs in one query but not both.

To do this you need to do `UNION` of both the queries and `INTERCEPT` of both the queries AND `MINUS` the `INTERCEPT` from the `UNION`. Like this

```
((SELECT T2.movie_title,T2.release_year
FROM(SELECT b.movie_title,b.release_year, COUNT(b.movie_title) as NUMMOVIES
FROM ACTOR a FULL OUTER JOIN CAST_MEMBER b ON a.actor_name=b.actor_name
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT c.actor_name FROM CAST_MEMBER c WHERE c.actor_name=a.actor_name)
GROUP BY b.movie_title,b.release_year) T2
WHERE T2.NUMMOVIES > 2) 

UNION

(SELECT a.movie_title,a.release_year
FROM MOVIE a
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(b.won) as Won_Counter
            FROM NOMINATION b
            WHERE b.movie_title=a.movie_title AND a.release_year=b.release_year AND b.won ='Yes') > 2))

MINUS

((SELECT T2.movie_title,T2.release_year
FROM(SELECT b.movie_title,b.release_year, COUNT(b.movie_title) as NUMMOVIES
FROM ACTOR a FULL OUTER JOIN CAST_MEMBER b ON a.actor_name=b.actor_name
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT c.actor_name FROM CAST_MEMBER c WHERE c.actor_name=a.actor_name)
GROUP BY b.movie_title,b.release_year) T2
WHERE T2.NUMMOVIES > 2) 

INTERSECT 

(SELECT a.movie_title,a.release_year
FROM MOVIE a
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(b.won) as Won_Counter
            FROM NOMINATION b
            WHERE b.movie_title=a.movie_title AND a.release_year=b.release_year AND b.won ='Yes') > 2))
```

Learn more about these operators [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)

I am sure there is a much better way to do this but we will need more information about your tables

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in several ways.  Here is a way that doesn't use `minus`:

```
with q1 as (
      <first query here>
     ),
     q2 as (
      <second query here>
     )
select q1.*
from q1
where not exists (select 1 from q2 where q2.movie = q1.movie);
```

This assumes that you want movies in the first query that are not in the second.  It also assumes that the second does not return a year; otherwise that would be part of the `where` condition.